Ubuntu Server pi tft display over GPIO
I've been searching all day but haven't had any luck on figuring this problem out. So far I've gotten Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS running on the my zero 2 W, I have worked out drivers and GPIO classification for the tft display, and I have confirmed that the display works with Kali OS as it has built in support for these devices, one click and it's setup. The last step that I'm stuck on is getting the system to output on the tft display. The answers I've gotten from Google are plentiful, varied, and for much earlier versions of Ubuntu Server. I know I'm missing something and I bet it's simple, any help is appreciated.
